# How to send data from v-for to event handler in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having problems with sending the right data to the event handler of a subcomponent in my Vue component.

Here is my code:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in [1, 2, 3]">
            <div @click=test(item)>test</div>
            <ConfirmModal v-if="showModal" @confirmed=test(item) />
            <button  v-on:click="showModal = true" ></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import ConfirmModal from 'ConfirmModal'
export default
{
    components: {ConfirmModal},
    data()
    {
        return {showModal: false}
    },
    methods:
    {
        test(item)
        {
          console.log(item);
          this.showModal = false;
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

And here is the code for a subcomponent:

```js
<template><div class="modal" @click.self="$emit('confirmed')">subtest</div></template>
```

So, basically, I here have an array of numbers and am using the `v-for` to iterate over an array.

For each item one `test` label, one subcomponent (containing a `subtest` label) and one button is created. When button is clicked, subcomponent is shown. When I click on the subcomponent (`subtest` label) it disappears.

`div` is a standard component which emmits `@click` events when it is clicked upon.

`confirmModal` is a very simple component which listens for `@click` events and redirects them into `@confirmed` events.

So, this code generates 3 times 3 items. When I click on any of the labels, `test` method is called which logs the value of the item.

When I click on any of the `test` labels, I get the correct value in the console, that is, `1` for the first item, `2` for the second item and so on.

But, when I click on any of the `subtest` labels, I allways get the `3`, whichever link I clicked. (If I change the order of items in the array, then I allways get whichever item I put on the last place in the array).

I do not understand what is going on here, it is the same method called on the same way. Why is `3` allways logged in console when I click on the `subtest` label?

If you wonder what is `class=modal` in my subcomponent used for, I have no idea. This is a skeleton of two components in a very complex project consisting of thousands of files built on top of the Liferay, and there are more then ten files where is `.modal` defined in many directories. So I am not sure from which file does this particular component load this class. I did not throw it out of this skeleton code just because when I remove this class from the div in the subcomponent, everything works fine. I have no idea why. How can a class stop the correct data from being received? I do not get this.

I know that this bug may not be reproducable, because I did not provide the definition of the `.modal` style, but I posted it anyway, because I hope that you can see something else in the code what is wrong or propose another way how to execute the `test` method on `@confirmed` event.

I am using Vue 2.

Comment: try `@confirmed="test"`

Comment: This does not work because ```test``` method requires a parameter.

Comment: the param is/should passed from the emit, could also use `@confirmed="() => test(item)"`

Comment: In my case, this does not work either. I allways get the last item, whatever ```subtest``` item I click. This has probably something to do with the class in the subitem but I can not seam to figure out what. In any case, thanx for trying.